# Creating a Linux installation on external SSD with both 32 and 64 bit boot options

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation, 64-bit, linux-kernel

So, my old 60G SSD now lives in an external USB enclosure. I want to install Linux in it, but I want to have the option to run on older hardware if necessary, so I would like to have both 32 and 64-bit boot options on the same drive, and partition if possible.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It's possible on the same partition, but use 2 partitions instead

Long answer: All mainstream distros will be unable to (or at least crippled if) have 32 and 64 bit versions in the same file system. There are some specialist possibilities, but this is not what you want to boot from this drive on arbitrary machines.

But all mainstream distros will work perfectly fine if you install a 64 Bit version on one partition, then a 32 Bit version on a second. If you aim for low-RAM machines add a 3rd partition as swap, this can be shared between both installations.

Comment: My main worry regarding this method is disk space. It's not terribad, as I can mount the other partition for extra space, but it's not exactly optimal, either. I suspect creating one partition slightly bigger than the other, and the smaller partition mounting the homedir from the bigger partition is probably the optimal solution.

Comment: DIsk space is of no concern here: We are talking of a 60G SSD, and a root partition of 8GB is more then enough for e.g. Ubuntu. You could unify `/home`, and even a lot of `/var`, resulting in even less storage waste.

Answer (score 1):

Just make two ext4 partitions e.g. with gparted and one swap partition. Then you can install two versions of linux. Most linux distributions should install and configure the boot manager correctly automatically. they will ask during installation where you want to install the grub boot manager. Just pick the usb ssd.